# Android Studio debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, xdebug, material-design

I want to learn material design for my upcoming android apps now I started this yesterday. I created a project and wanted to build and run it for the 1st time. (I use my phone to debug and build instead of the emulator)

but now I keep getting this error:

```
"Waiting for device.
Target device: lge-nexus_5-0647e7060036ef6b
Uploading file
    local path: /home/jelleroggie/AndroidStudioProjects/Test-App/mobile/build/outputs/apk/mobile-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/test.computing.roggie.test_app
Installing test.computing.roggie.test_app
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/test.computing.roggie.test_app"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/test.computing.roggie.test_app
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]"
```

And the only thing I added / changed is adding the  tag.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="20"/>
```

note: it already gave this error before I added this line.

I would really appreaciate your help.

Thank you up front for your time

Kind Regards,
Jelle Roggekamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your build.graddle file, and in particular defaultConfig and compileSdkVersion, as it sounds that you have perhaps the minimum sdk to L in gradle (this may have been done automatically by Android Studio).

The manifest isn't used for building but only for filtering on Google play store, so what matters, in terms of building the app in Android Studio, is the build graddle file.